# 1997 pontiac firebird ignition key lock cylinder problems

Tags: starting, pontiac, ignition-switch, firebird

Wires going to cylinder are broke off like 1 to 2 inches which makes it next to impossible to splice into without them breaking again once I turn the key. Can I take the cylinder apart and replace the wires from the inside. O'Reilly's did sell me an ignition, but the key has no chip. Is it possible to use it?

Comment: which wires? for the passlock? or for the switch? you can unpin repair the wires and repin either way. or buy a harness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the ignition cylinder you bought, but you'll need to get a key with the correct resistor in it, then cut it to match the key which came from O'Reilly's. To get the correct resistor, just measure the resistance to your original key. This will match what's in the security system. Put the new cylinder in your column, get the new key with the right chip, and you should be golden.

There are 15 resistances for the chip in the VATS system. Here is what they should be. Use a multimeter on the ohm setting to figure out what your car has now:

```
# 1 VATS Key Resistor Value 0.402 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P1
# 2 VATS Key Resistor Value 0.523 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P2/B82P2
# 3 VATS Key Resistor Value 0.681 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P3/B82P3
# 4 VATS Key Resistor Value 0.887 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P4/B82P4
# 5 VATS Key Resistor Value 1.130 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P5/B82P5
# 6 VATS Key Resistor Value 1.470 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P6/B82P6
# 7 VATS Key Resistor Value 1.870 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P7/B82P7
# 8 VATS Key Resistor Value 2.370 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P8/B82P8
# 9 VATS Key Resistor Value 3.010 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P9/B82P9
# 10 VATS Key Resistor Value 3.740 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P10/B82P10
# 11 VATS Key Resistor Value 4.750 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P11/B82P11
# 12 VATS Key Resistor Value 6.040 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P12/B82P12
# 13 VATS Key Resistor Value 7.500 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P13/B82P13
# 14 VATS Key Resistor Value 9.530 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P14/B82P14
# 15 VATS Key Resistor Value 11.801 Ohms Key Blank Number B62P15/B82P15
```

The above was pulled from [this website](http://automotiveandcommerciallocksmith.blogspot.com/2014/10/vats-system-chart.html)

Comment: That or take to locksmith to re-pin to old key.